# how to replace a certain value in string?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3, flexbuilder

I am using Flexbuilder with sdk 3.5. I convert an `int` to a `binary string`. Now I want to replace binary value at certain index. How can I do this?

I tried following but it did not work;

```
binaryStr[0] = "0";
```

and

```
binaryStr[0] = '0';
```

Comment: why do you need it as a binary string to do this? why not just use `&` and `|` to turn bits on and off in the integer?

Comment: And is binaryStr[0] the most significant bit or the least significant bit of the int?

Comment: I'm also intrigued as to what you are trying to do

Comment: can you post the exact code.that might help

Answer (score 1):

You could use String.split() to convert your String into an Array, then change what you want, and finally convert the resulting Array into a String with Array.join() ?

Comment: `split()` and `join()` is a terrible way to replace text as it's slow and each time you call `split()`, you're creating a new Array. Use `String.replace()`. As a bonus, you can pass a `RegExp` as the search parameter, and a `Function` as the replace.

Comment: I know, but the asker wants to replace a value at a certain index.